# How to use dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a game of dictionary rock paper scissors and I was going to use a lot of if and elif but my CS Lab tech told me I could use a dictionary in python. How would I use it to make a game of rock paper scissors?

My plan is to use a function and pull one letter out of a list and try to compare if its a win the game says "win", if loss says "loss" and if a tie print "tie" and ask if you want to play again. But that's as far as I got.

Comment: can you also paste earlier code and show what you have tried and what is expected and not working for you?

Comment: You can make a dict like `{'rs': 'win', 'rr': 'tie',}` etc.

Comment: this might be useful for you: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80067/simple-rock-paper-scissors-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Assuming two players, there are three possible end-game states (win, lose, tie) and nine different outcomes (rock-rock, paper-scissors, etc). If you wanted to do this as a dictionary, you could create three keys - one for each end-game state - where each value is a list containing the possible games that lead to that outcome. These games can be stored as ordered pairs where the first value of the tuple represents the player's choice and the second value is the opponent's. e.g., the key-value pair for all possible win-states would be the following:

```
"win" : [("rock", "scissors"), ("paper", "rock"), ("scissors", "paper")]
```

Once you have your `dict` of all possible games, it's just a matter of iterating through each end-state key and checking whether or not the `tuple` of the choices made by the player and the opponent is contained within the `list` value associated with that key. If it is, then you've found the outcome of the game.

With this in mind, you could do something like the following:

```
from random import choice

answers = {"yes" : ["yes", "y"],
           "no"  : ["no",  "n"]}

choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

games = {"win"  : [(choices[0], choices[2]), 
                   (choices[1], choices[0]), 
                   (choices[2], choices[1])],

         "lose" : [(choices[0], choices[1]), 
                   (choices[1], choices[2]), 
                   (choices[2], choices[0])],

         "tie"  : [(choices[0], choices[0]), 
                   (choices[1], choices[1]), 
                   (choices[2], choices[2])]}

print("Let's play \"Rock, paper, scissors\"!\n")

replay = True

while replay:

    player = ""

    while player.lower() not in choices:

        player = input("Rock, paper, or scissors?: ")

    opponent = choice(choices)

    print("You chose {}.".format(player.lower()))
    print("Your opponent chose {}.".format(opponent))

    for outcome in games:

        if (player.lower(), opponent) in games[outcome]:

            print("You {} against your opponent!\n".format(outcome))

    replay_decision = ""

    while replay_decision.lower() not in (answers["yes"] + answers["no"]):

        replay_decision = input("Would you like to play again? [y/n]: ")

        if replay_decision.lower() in answers["no"]:

            replay = False

print("\nThanks for playing!")
```

Which produces the following sample output:

```
Let's play "Rock, paper, scissors"!

Rock, paper, or scissors?: rock
You chose rock.
Your opponent chose rock.
You tie against your opponent!

Would you like to play again? [y/n]: y
Rock, paper, or scissors?: paper
You chose paper.
Your opponent chose rock.
You win against your opponent!

Would you like to play again? [y/n]: y
Rock, paper, or scissors?: scissors
You chose scissors.
Your opponent chose paper.
You win against your opponent!

Would you like to play again? [y/n]: n

Thanks for playing!
```